# QGIS,The line is divided into small segments, how to associate the original line with all the small segments

Tags: qgis, line

Shape1 is the base of all.
Shape3 is based on Shape1, they have the same Polyline and id, but different attributes.

Now Shape1 is updated to Shape2.
Example: Originally line segment A becomes line segment B, C, and D. One Feature becomes 3 Features, and the IDs of these three Features are different. The only association is that the Polyline merge of B, C, and D will be the Polyline of A.

I want to change the line segment A'(Polyline same as Shape1) of Shape3 into B',C', and D'(Polyline same as Shape2).
(BCD) and (B'C'D') have corresponding Polyline and id, but have the same attributes as the original line segment A' (Shape3).

There are multiple such line segments that need to be handled automatically.
Any plugin or PyQGIS suggestions?

[image]
[image]

Comment: Are you asking how to use `join attributes by location`?

Comment: Or using Field Calculator with `overlay_nearest`

Comment: Please add some details as the question is not completely clear: What's the relation between shape 1 and 3? What role does shape 1 play or your question? You simply want to divide shape 3 in three parts, preserving the attributes. How do you divide the line into sub-linestrings?

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Erik and Babel.

Yes, "join attributes by location" can solve my problem
"within" can associate A' with B,C,D.
This is enough for me to build B',C',D'.

[image]